# How to get a flex element to be aligned with top of my sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, inline

[image]
[image]

The following is what my website currently looks like,
I made a side navigation bar that will have links.
Placeholder items 'test2' and 'test3'.
I need to get it to start at the top of page.

My ultimate goal is to toggle the sidebar when menu icon is clicked; therefore, the content of the page needs to resize to fill the page, hence why I used flex.
Here is my code:

```html
     <div class="sidebar" style="
        display: inline-block;
        margin:0px;  width: 175px; 
        background-color: black; 
        box-shadow: 1px 0 3px -1px white;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;">
        
        <hr>
        <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">test</a> <hr>
        <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">test</a> <hr>
        <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">test</a> <hr>

    </div>
    

        <div class="row"
        style=" 
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;">
    
            <div class='column' 
            style="flex: auto;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 15px;
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0);
                text-align: center;
                overflow: hidden;">
                Test2
            </div>
            <div class='column'>
                Test3
            </div>
        </div>
```

It is quite apparent I am really struggling with understanding flow of elements on a page. Is there a detailed video that can explain this all?

Comment: You should be creating a separate CSS file and applying properties to your classes instead of using so much inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this??

```html
<div class="sidebar" style="
        display: inline-block;
        margin:0px;  width: 175px; 
        background-color: black; 
        box-shadow: 1px 0 3px -1px white;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;">
        
        <hr>
        <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">test</a> <hr>
        <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">test</a> <hr>
        <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">test</a> <hr>

    </div>
    

        <div class="row"
        style=" 
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;">
    
            <div class='column' 
            style="flex: auto;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 15px;
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0);
                text-align: center;
                overflow: hidden;
                ">
                Test2
            </div>
            <div class='column'>
                Test3
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: When using Absolute, the footer jumps up. Maybe I should try Table, Row, Column? I want each "column" (side nav bar, test2, and test3) to overflow independently.

Comment: As long as you know where exactly you want to put the side bar thats absolutely will work. Remember "Absolute Position" The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

Comment: I don't have your entire code. You can try putting bottom:0 on your footer and put height:100vh on your body so you can still view base on your viewport.

Comment: Hi, I figured it out. Thanks for your help.!

Answer (score 0):

[image: What it looks like right now]I figured it out. This is what I was going for! If I add more links to the navbar on the side, it overflows but maintains a single page size. Thanks again!!

```
    <div class="row" style="height: calc(100% - 120px); ">
    <div class="sidebar" style="overflow:hidden; overflow-y: visible;"> 
        <div style="">
    <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">Browse</a> <hr>
    <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">Rabbit Hole</a> <hr>
    <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">Untitled Game</a> <hr>
    <a href="" style="display:block; padding: 15px;">Shop</a> <hr>
</div>
    </div>
    
        <div class='column' >
            Test2
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
            Test3
        </div>
    </div>
```